# How can I improve this question about undefined behavior and comparison operators?

Tags: support, specific-question, question-quality

I recently asked this question about comparing pointers and undefined behavior:

[Is comparing two pointers with < undefined behavior if they are both cast to an integer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639853/is-comparing-two-pointers-with-undefined-behavior-if-they-are-both-cast-to-an)

However, I have gotten 2 downvotes on it, which shows me that I could do more to improve it. How can I do that?

Comment: Your vote tally is at net zero right now.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It was at -2 before.

Comment: Honestly I'm not seeing much in the way to worry about things.  The fact that it was at -2 before and is at 0 now is indicative that four people have come to this question and *on average* believe that it's alright.

Answer (score -10):

Per the downvote arrow mouseover text: Is your question unclear? Does it show no research effort?

The linked post asks two questions (--"unclear").

> Is this still undefined behavior if they're not members of the same array? If it is, what are some ways that I could make my code legal?

First it asks whether the behaviour is undefined. Then apparently (--"unclear") it asks what code would be defined, but it doesn't say what the code should do (--"unclear"). (I suppose "make my code legal" is trying to say, "write code with the functionality I have in mind".) If the given code is undefined then it does not communicate what you hope or suspect it to do, and you don't otherwise say.

You don't reference any definitions or regulations or presentations re your question's behaviour (including its operators & casting) to show/argue that it is or isn't or might be or might not be defined--"no research effort".

> I didn't find that necessary, as it's a fairly common example of undefined behavior. I can add a quote if that helps.

The logic & point of that comment is not clear. You say "it's a fairly common example of undefined behavior" but the linked post asks whether it is undefined. Your post show no research on the 2 question it asks.

So ask one clear question & reflect research. Suggest you ask the first question. Then in a later post say what you want to accomplish & ask a clear question about being stuck doing it. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: And how do I improve the question?

Comment: Clearly, ask one clear question that reflects research.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: I would argue that this is overly generic advice.  "Undefined behavior" is well-known vernacular in C and C++, and anyone who's versed in the language would be able to establish what is and is not defined.  My concern is that there's less of an issue of clarity, and more of an issue of domain knowledge here with your evaluation.

Comment: @Makoto They have given zero specification for what they want their code to do and zero research about the definedness of the code they wrote so I don't know what you can mean by "too generic". If they wrote *something* then something more specific would become relevant.

Comment: @philipxy See the quotes to C11. What do you think now?

Comment: @JL2210 My criticisms (answer & comments here & comments there) have nothing to do with the undefinedness of the first code block, and the question you ask in your SO post doesn't ask about it, it's just some unnecessary introductory context. PS What does "compare these two locations in memory" mean? You appear to be trying to say something about your implementation that the standard doesn't address. Objects not part of the same array have no ordering in the abstract C machine. You still seem to be expecting us to know things about what you expect & want to do that you are not saying.

Comment: @JL2210 Please do not write things intended to insult. You haven't shown research & you haven't said what specification you want a code block to meet, and I am just trying to help you by telling you that.